# Connecting to Wired Connection Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, wired-networking

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I need someone to tell me the steps I need to take to fix this issue...

It's not my Internet problem because I'm able to wired in on my other laptop. So it's obviously something wrong with my laptop. It makes no sense that It was working perfectly fine yesterday and then today dead... I did not installed anything .

**Things to know**

- My mac address is not blocked (contacted my Network Administrator)
- Wired connections works when I got home but not at work. Tested the wired connection on another laptop and it works
- Ethernet port is not damaged. Test it out with an adapter(same outcome)

What are the steps I need to take to diagnose this?

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:fa:5b:2b:96:84  
          inet6 addr: fe80::82fa:5bff:fe2b:9684/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2852 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:3934 (3.9 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:5c:e8:01:4a  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:5cff:fee8:14a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:54625 (54.6 KB)  TX bytes:61318 (61.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:298825 (298.8 KB)  TX bytes:298825 (298.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:34:d9:64:d9:a8  
          inet addr:192.168.2.36  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a634:d9ff:fe64:d9a8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4224848 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:553000 (553.0 KB)
```

**route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.3.251   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: eth0
       version: 12
       serial: 80:fa:5b:2b:96:84
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:126 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df214000-df214fff memory:df210000-df213fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 3a
       serial: a4:34:d9:64:d9:a8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.2.0-42-generic firmware=25.30.13.0 ip=192.168.2.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:128 memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 00:e0:5c:e8:01:4a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.08.1 (2015/07/28) duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

**nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | grep IP4**

```
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.2.36/22, gw = 192.168.3.251
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
```

**nm-tool**

```
    - Device: eth1 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8152
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:E0:5C:E8:01:4A

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on


- Device: wlan0  [staybridge] --------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        A4:34:D9:64:D9:A8

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:BF:2C:60, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:B7:31:F8, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:BF:2C:70, Freq 2442 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:B7:32:04, Freq 2447 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 37
    *staybridge:     Infra, 00:02:6F:CB:F5:60, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:CB:F5:64, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:BF:2C:84, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55
    CableWiFi:       Infra, 50:1C:BF:49:7B:23, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35
    staybridge:      Infra, 00:02:6F:E9:DB:C0, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70
    EnGeniusBF2C78:  Infra, 00:02:6F:BF:2C:78, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59
    TWCWiFi:         Infra, 50:1C:BF:49:7B:22, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.2.36
    Prefix:          22 (255.255.252.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.3.251

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             8.8.4.4


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        80:FA:5B:2B:96:84

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by 'not working' in this context. As it currently stands, your problem is not really obvious and can be inferred differently.

Comment: It detects my ethernet cable when it is plugged in. It goes in this loading process and then it just gives up and ends up going on the wifi. I'm sorry I don't know how else to explain this. @Larssend

Comment: I think that's enough, for now at least.

Comment: @Larssend Hey I updated my post for the nm-tool cli. I'm not too familiar with networking but is that normal that the eth1 interface pops up when I plug in my cable? Isn't it suppose to just go into the eth0 one?